# ComponentDidUpdate calling infinte times with setState

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm trying to change the state, changing an object an it called infinite times

Code

```
componentDidUpdate (prevState) {
    if (prevState.tab !== this.state.tab) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState.tableConfiguration,
            columns: getColumnsConfig(this.state.tab)
        }))
    }
}
```

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Any suggestion

Comment: your condition check is on state.tab, shouldn't you update it in the setState() ?

Comment: You're checking if `tab` changed, which it didn't since you're changing `columns`.. Also you're spreading `tableConfiguration` into state which is changing the shape of your state which looks wrong.

Comment: What does `getColumnsConfig(this.state.tab)` do?

Comment: @HMR changes the configuration of one table to another, for example if I have in:
table 1: dog, cats
in table 2 I have: horses, parrots

Comment: Does it do anything with sate?

Comment: @Dominic now is more clear, but how should I do it?

Comment: You are comparing two objects `{} !== {}` is always true which causes an infinite loop.

Comment: @Jonathan plz post what your state object should look like

Comment: @Dominic 
`this.state = {
            ...defaultState,
            tableConfiguration: {
                ...defaultState.tableConfiguration,
                columns: getColumnsConfig(ONBOARDING_ORDER_DETAILS_TABS.ACTIVATION_TAB)
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks of your comments I find one solution.

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.tab !== this.state.tab) {
        const newConfig = {
            ...prevState.tableConfiguration,
            columns: getColumnsConfig(this.state.tab)
        }
        this.setState({ tableConfiguration: newConfig })
    }
}
```